# Return empty instead of zero when summing range

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, array-formulas

I'm summing rows down a range using `ARRAYFORMULA()`.

The number of rows in this range will vary over time, due to be linked to a data source that will grow. This is fine on the sheet because there's nothing else below. However, this means I can't limit the range on the array, leading to it summing empty rows at the bottom.

The complication I'm having is that where there's no data to be summed, the formula is returning 0 instead of an error or nothing. I'd like it to return nothing/empty.

Here's the formula for summing down the range by row:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(K2:AN),ROW(AN2:AN)),ROW(AN2:AN),K2:AN))`

My typical approach to return empty is nested `IF()` statements, but this is incredibly bulky. There has to be a better way than:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SUMIF(IF(...)...)<>0,SUMIF(IF(...)...)),"")`

I've tried these lighter approaches to return empty instead, with no luck:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUMIF(IF(...)...),""))`

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(IF(ISNUMBER(...))...))`

Comment: ca you share a simple sample sheet? I'm confused why are you using the column and row function  - I do this type of array formula often though so Im sure I can offer you a solution if I can get a better idea of what the end result is supposed ot be

Answer (score 0):

Writing a comment that there is no easy way to get this done unless you want to exclude errors I found an easy way to get this done because you want to exclude zeros and this allows us to make an error very easily.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
  1 / (1 / SUMIF(
    IF(COLUMN(K2:AN), ROW(AN2:AN)),
    ROW(AN2:AN),
    K2:AN)), 
  ""))
```